# Need help with correction on a Spanish text

Tags: español-neutral

> Los días de la semana que más me gustan son los viernes y fines de
> semana. Los viernes es el último día en el que me concentro en los
> estudios y el trabajo, luego puedo relajarme durante ese día y durante
> el fin de semana. Luego suelo leer libros, ver películas y hacer otras
> cosas.

Could someone help me correct this? I am somewhat new to Spanish, and the question I was asked in my textbook was this question ”¿Qué día de la semana te gusta más? ¿Por qué?” and I had to use Google translate, but I would like to know how to answer in the most basic way possible without special words.

Comment: I am sorry but asking for corrections to a text is off-topic on this site. See https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for details. If you have specific parts which you are concerned about you can ask separate questions about the underlying grammatical issue. To get you started it should be _El viernes es ..._  not _Los viernes es ..._

Comment: Learning advice: Go read about how to use the verb gustar in Spanish.  You will never learn a language using google flub-up.